# How to fulfill new requirement for built-in read actions to generate action only after 10 seconds of loading page?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-opengraph

I have submitted built-in read action yesterday and today it came up with changes needed tag stating that

> We are updating the requirements for built-in read actions so that the
>   built-in action is only generated 10 seconds after a user lands on a
>   page with an article - this is a strong indication that the user has
>   read an article

I am using php and i think we cant do this in php because php is server side language, so should i use JavaScript or is there any better option?
Thanks!

Comment: you are right about using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use Javascript to publish the User's Read action. Something like (completely untested)

```
setTimeout(function() {
  FB.api('/me/news.reads', {article: document.location.href}, function(response) {
    // note the response if you want
  });
}, 10000);
```